# Creating JSON in required format - Java

Tags: java, jquery, json

I am not very experienced in this so need help.I need following things to be done :
1. Want to traverse a folder structure in a content management repository.
2. Want to create JSON Object of the folder in child-node form.
3. Json data will be used to create tree using jQuery

Json format:

```
var data = [
        {
          text: "Parent 1",
          nodes: [
            {
              text: "Child 1",
              nodes: [
                {
                  text: "Grandchild 1"
                },
                {
                  text: "Grandchild 2"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              text: "Child 2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          text: "Parent 2"
        },
        {
          text: "Parent 3"
        },
        {
          text: "Parent 4"
        },
        {
          text: "Parent 5"
        }
      ];
```

My Java method is like this:

```
public static void displayIt(File node){

    System.out.println(node.getAbsoluteFile());

    if(node.isDirectory()){
        String[] subNote = node.list();
        for(String filename : subNote){
            displayIt(new File(node, filename));
        }
    }

}
```

I am Struggling to frame strategy to create JSON object and Array to depict this.

Please can you help me.

Comment: can please post your folder structure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read all files or folder from content management repository using recursion than use below function :

```
public static MyFolder readFiles(File file,List<MyFolder> myfolder,MyFolder childObj)
    {
        try
        {
            List<MyFolder> childArray = new ArrayList<MyFolder>();
            if(file.isDirectory())
            {
                File[] file_array = file.listFiles();
                if(file_array.length == 0 ){
                    childObj.text = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    myfolder.add(childObj);
                    childObj = new MyFolder();
                }else{
                    childObj.text = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    childArray = childObj.nodes;
                    if(childArray == null)
                        childArray = new ArrayList<MyFolder>();
                }
                for(File tempFile : file_array)
                {
                    if(tempFile.isDirectory())
                    {
                        childObj = readFiles(tempFile,myfolder,childObj);
                        if(childObj.text != null)
                            myfolder.add(childObj);
                        childObj = new MyFolder();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MyFolder obj = new MyFolder();
                        obj.text = tempFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        childArray.add(obj);
                    }
                }
                childObj.nodes = childArray;
            }
            else
            {
                childObj.text = file.getAbsolutePath();
                myfolder.add(childObj);
                childObj = new MyFolder();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return childObj;
    }
```

MyFolder Class :

```
class MyFolder 
{
    String text;
    List<MyFolder> nodes;
}
```

You need some JSON utility or API to convert your class into json string. I have used [GSON google API](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert my `List<MyFolder>` to JSON string.

Below is my test Class to test above :

```
List<MyFolder> myFolder = new ArrayList<MyFolder>();
File file = new File("D:/test");
MyFolder childArray = new MyFolder();
readFiles(file,myFolder,childArray);

Gson json = new Gson();
System.out.println(json.toJson(myFolder));
```

Output is :

```
[
    {
        "text": "D:\\test\\test1\\test12",
        "nodes": [
            {
                "text": "D:\\test\\test1\\test12\\test12.txt"
            },
            {
                "text": "D:\\test\\test1\\test12\\test12_2.txt"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "text": "D:\\test\\test2"
    },
    {
        "text": "D:\\test\\test3"
    }
]
```

Last thing remaining is just passed this to client side and process JSON to generate tree stucture.
May this will help you.

Comment: See my updated answer. after so many tried it seems to be what you need as output.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way in JAVA to produce a JSON object from different collection types - Flexjson. [Here](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) you can find most essential information about Flexjson. In short, the command looks like this:

```
String jsonString = new flexjson.JSONSerializer().deepSerialize(myCollection);
```

Jquery perfectly understands the resulting JSON object and you can easily access the contents in JQuery like this:

`jsonString["column1"]`

So, you can just save data in an Arra/Map/whatewer is suitable for your situation and then translate in to JSON.

Hope it helps, I use this method every time I need a JSON string and works perfectly for me.

Comment: My problem is about creating JSON object in Recursive method. While still maintaining the parent child relationship.

Comment: @VJV I'm not an expert and I'm not sure I understood your problem so I may be wrong, but I don't think it's possible to keep such relationship in JSON.

Comment: In otherwords, I traverse Folder Structure in Recursive Method. I want to build JSON array/object explained above.

Comment: @VJV Can you just create full structure, then build Json out of it (using the serializer I advised) and then access nodes? In Jquery it is like this: var array = jsonString["column1"]; var node = array["Parent 1"]; This works, but I;m not 100% sure it's what you want. I don't really get the problem - you're able to build the structure, have the command to serialize it into JSON, so what is the problem?